# Declare module and import definitions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have written TypeScript types for an interface that can be implemented by multiple other npm packages (namely [Noble bindings](https://github.com/noble/noble)).

It's quite a long file

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
import StrictEventEmitter from "strict-event-emitter-types";

export type PeripheralUuid = string;
export type Address = string;
export type AddressType = "public" | "random" | "unknown";
export type Descriptor = string;

export interface Advertisement {
  localName: string;
  txPowerLevel: number;
  serviceUuids: BluetoothServiceUUID[];
  manufacturerData?: Buffer;
  serviceData?: Buffer;
}

export interface Methods {
  init(): void;
  startScanning(
    serviceUuids: BluetoothServiceUUID[],
    allowDuplicates: boolean
  ): void;

// ...
```

You can see all of it here https://github.com/LukasBombach/sblendid/blob/master/packages/sblendid/types/bindings.d.ts

I cannot control the implementations of this file, yet I know they must conform these types. I am importing these files and I am trying to tell typescript that when I import any of those implementations, like

```
import BindingsMacOs from "noble-bindings-macos";
import BindingsWindows from "noble-bindings-windows";
import BindingsLinux from "noble-bindings-linux";
```

because if I do just that I will get an error or a warning

Now I was thinking I could define my types once as `bindings.d.ts` and write module declarations that import those bindings:

```
import Bindings from "./bindings"

declare module "noble-bindings-macos" {
  export default Bindings;
}
```

But I was wrong:

> Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'noble-bindings-macos' resolves to an untyped module at '/Users/lbombach/Projekte/DecentEspresso/sblendid/packages/noble-bindings-macos/index.js', which cannot be augmented. ts(2665)

If I remove the `import` statement and just export something it works fine.

Is there any way I can import those declarations and reuse them for multiple module declarations?